# JWPLayer 6 in Firefox Must Load Entire OGG File Before Playing?

Tags: firefox, streaming, jwplayer, ogg, webm

Site:

http://www.chicagobluesnetwork.com/Shows/Listen/sharon-lewis-texas-fire-4

u: anothertest
p: testpass1

In FireFox:
The first track is relatively small, but if you try the second track you will notice a long pause before it plays as the entire file must load before it plays

In Chrom:
Track plays right away as it downloads

I've seen html 5 embedded ogg play right away in firefox so is this just an issue with jwplayer or am I not sending the right httpheaders?

I am using this to send the file:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
Response.Headers.Remove("Cache-Control");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes 0-" + (stream.Length - 1).ToString() + "/" + stream.Length.ToString());
return File(stream, file.MimeType);
```

Is there anything I can do to have OGG files play right away? The same thing happens with webm video.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with how the ogg/webm is encoded?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with WebM video, plays immediately in chrome, FireFox seems to wait until the entire video downloads... Did you find a solution?  Also, I am finding that in FF, the video jumps right to the end before playing.

Comment: It has to do with the accept range header, make sure your file handler can properly handle range requests